# How to get specific column from associated value?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to know how I can take `value` associated to `company_working_plan` (name). I'm using `MySqlCommand` but I don't know if is possible get the specific column value without iterate on all rows.

```
NAME                |  VALUE
COMPANY_WORKING_PLAN  XX
```

Comment: `SELECT specific_value_column_name FROM table WHERE some_column = @p1` where @p1 would be the the name value

Comment: Couldn't you just a `WHERE` clause to your SQL statement? like `WHERE name = 'company_working_plan'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

```
select value from tablename where name = 'company_working_plan'
```

Comment: @Sandokan:- Yes thats correct. Have a look at an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Ok thank you for the help I very appreciate. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT name, value 
FROM Tablename
WHERE ID = '13'
```

that is for the row you highlighted in your image if you want every row and only the value in the column as well as the company name try this:

```
SELECT name, value
FROM tablename
```

You edited the question after I posted this and it is still a bit confusing but I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT name, value 
FROM tablename
WHERE value = 'company_working_plan'
```